# how to get dynamic dataframes created in function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following main dataframe in python

```
   ID       Date          Product_Name     transaction
   1        01-01-2018    MS               234
   1        01-02-2018    MS               2345
   1        02-02-2018    MS               234
   2        01-01-2018    HSD              2312
   2        02-02-2018    HSD              2234
   3        01-01-2018    MS               2123
   3        02-02-2018    MS               345
```

Now,I want to subset dataframes based on `ID` and `Product_Name` more of a dynamic nature. So from above dataframe it will create 3 dynamic dataframes(Based on unique values from `ID` and `Product_Name` columnns) with following subset filters and name it like `MS_1`,`HSD_2`,`MS_3`

```
   ID = 1 and Product_Name = 'MS'
   ID = 2 and Product_Name = 'HSD'
   ID = 3 and Product_Name = 'MS'
```

Is it possible to do it in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better is create `dictionary of DataFrame`s:

```
d = {'{}_{}'.format(k[1], k[0]):v for k, v in df.groupby(['ID','Product_Name'])}
print (d)
{'MS_1':    ID        Date Product_Name  transaction
0   1  01-01-2018           MS          234
1   1  01-02-2018           MS         2345
2   1  02-02-2018           MS          234, 'HSD_2':    ID     Date Product_Name  transaction
3   2  01-01-2018          HSD         2312
4   2  02-02-2018          HSD         2234, 'MS_3':    ID     Date Product_Name  transaction
5   3  01-01-2018           MS         2123
6   3  02-02-2018           MS          345}
```

And for select use:

```
print (d['MS_1'])
   ID        Date Product_Name  transaction
0   1  01-01-2018           MS          234
1   1  01-02-2018           MS         2345
2   1  02-02-2018           MS          234

print (d['HSD_2'])
   ID        Date Product_Name  transaction
3   2  01-01-2018          HSD         2312
4   2  02-02-2018          HSD         2234
```

EDIT:

@jpp suggestion for create keys by tuples:

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby(['ID','Product_Name'])))
print (d)
{(1, 'MS'):    ID        Date Product_Name  transaction
0   1  01-01-2018           MS          234
1   1  01-02-2018           MS         2345
2   1  02-02-2018           MS          234, (2, 'HSD'): ID   Date Product_Name  transaction
3   2  01-01-2018          HSD         2312
4   2  02-02-2018          HSD         2234, (3, 'MS'):  ID    Date Product_Name  transaction
5   3  01-01-2018           MS         2123
6   3  02-02-2018           MS          345}


print (d[(1, 'MS')])
   ID        Date Product_Name  transaction
0   1  01-01-2018           MS          234
1   1  01-02-2018           MS         2345
2   1  02-02-2018           MS          234

print (d[(2, 'HSD')])
   ID        Date Product_Name  transaction
3   2  01-01-2018          HSD         2312
4   2  02-02-2018          HSD         2234
```

And for convert back to big DataFrame with all subDataFrames use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat(dict(tuple(df.groupby(['ID','Product_Name'])))).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   ID        Date Product_Name  transaction
0   1  01-01-2018           MS          234
1   1  01-02-2018           MS         2345
2   1  02-02-2018           MS          234
3   2  01-01-2018          HSD         2312
4   2  02-02-2018          HSD         2234
5   3  01-01-2018           MS         2123
6   3  02-02-2018           MS          345
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I convert back to dataframe again?

Comment: @Neil - If need DataFrame use `pd.concat(dict(tuple(df.groupby(['ID','Product_Name']))))`

Comment: @jpp - Thank you.

Comment: @jezrael will `pd.concat` give me 3 different dataframes?

Comment: @Neil - No, `print (d[(1, 'MS')])` or `print (d['MS_1'])` return DataFrames

Comment: But then this is something I will have to do it manually. I do not want to do that, is there anything else which can convert it to different dataframes?

Comment: @Neil - Maybe it is a bit confused, but `(d['MS_1'])` is like `df`, so if want called `MS_1` for DataFrame only use `d['MS_1']`, check it `print (type(d['MS_1']))`